# SonarQube doesn't flag code smell identical to one it does

Tags: java, sonarqube, try-with-resources

We are testing the introduction of some SonarQube rules in our codebase that have to do with flagging openings of connections that are not closed in `catch` or `finally` blocks, and missed opportunities to use try-with-resources. The rules flag the following code block:

```java
final Connection connection = jThalesDs.getConnection();
final PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(String.format(GET_SERVER_IDS_AND_TEST_LOGINS, dbSchemaProps.getOracleJThales()));
try {
    // Some calls that may or may not throw something
} catch(Throwable exc){
    // Closing the resources and re-throwing the exception
    pstmt.close();
    connection.close();
    throw exc;
}
// Whoops, forgot to include a finally block where we close the connections.
```

As can be verified through this screenshot:

[image: Code smell that is flagged by SQ]

In the very same file, however, a more serious violation of the same rule is not being flagged as either a bug or a code smell, and SonarQube instead focuses on the genericity of the class being thrown (a `RuntimeException`):

```java
final Connection conn = jThalesDs.getConnection();
try  {
     // More calls that may or may not throw
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    // Whoops, forgot to close the connection if not null!
    throw new RuntimeException(TEST_LOGINS_DB_ERROR, ex);
}
```

[image: Failing to reproduce a scenario with an even more grave violation of the rules.]

So, to recap. In the same file, I have a bug and code smell that *is* being caught by SonarQube, and it concerns the fact that I am not closing resources in a `finally` block. However, in an even more grievous violation of the same rules, in the same file, those rules are not triggered.

What could be going on here? FWIW, we are running the latest LTS, 9.9.2.